# Word 2010 table PDFd shows faint lines above and below text

Tags: mac, pdf, microsoft-word-2010

When PDFing a Word 2010 doc (OS Windows 10), shaded table cells show faint lines surrounding the text when viewed on certain Macs (not on mine, but on my client's Mac).

The left and right lines correspond to the R/L edges of the cell margins, but the top and bottom lines do not. There are 2.25 pt white lines applied to this shaded cell, but not to the paragraph (and the visible lines — see pic attached) surrounding the text are nowhere near 2.25 pts).

I've searched on this to no avail (no, it's not a transparency issue, yes, I've upped the res to 300ppi in the PDF) so I'm hoping anyone here has any insight as to why this keeps happening. I can't test it myself, and am loathe to make the client test on that end. Stuck.

[image: screen shot of PDFd Word table showing lines surrounding text that only appears on certain Macs]

Comment: If you (or your client) zoom in, do these line get thicker or remain very thin? If they don't get thicker it might just be some display issue. If they get thicker then the lines are actually (graphically) in the file. Also, are the lines visible when printing the page?

Comment: (Just saw this today (!), Atzmon—thank you!) They remain thin on zoom. They aren't graphically in the file. They aren't visible when the page is printed.